# B-1 visa, bank statement issue

Tags: visas, usa

Suppose someone is inviting me from the USA and he shows his bank statements to prove that he is the person inviting me for a tourist visa, is there any need for me to produce my own bank statements? Since his would be taking care of everything, I just want to know.

I am from Nigeria.

Comment: It depends. When I invited my aunt and parents to visit, all they showed was my bank statement. But then my parents are older, and it is generally accepted in Ghana where I am from that many children abroad support their parents financially. Being from Nigeria your chances of getting a US visa are already slim. I would advice you to have every reasonable support document, and a **personal** bank statement is expected.

Comment: See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab). Just because your friend has money does nothing to convince the consulate that _you_ have a stable economic situation at home that you'd wish to return to after your proposed visit.

Comment: The consular officers seldom ask to see any bank statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does every tourist need a sponsor?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114716/does-every-tourist-need-a-sponsor); related [Should I submit bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: @Giorgio This question about US visas is certainly not a duplicate of a question about UK visas. The question about whether every tourist needs a sponsor is related but, again, not a duplicate. It's not really helpful to edit the automatic close vote message to include several possible duplicates. Please pick the closest single duplicate for your close vote (that's the one that others get to vote on by default) and post a separate comment if you wish to highlight other relevant questions.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ty, wil do.

Comment: @Giorgio Thanks! And thanks for highlighting other relevant questions, because that definitely is useful to the asker.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may need to information regarding your financial status. The [US State Department guidance](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) clarifies (emphasis mine):

> Additional documents may be requested to establish if you are qualified. For example, additional requested documents may include evidence of:
>
> - The purpose of your trip,
> - Your intent to depart the United States after your trip, and/or
> - **Your ability to pay all costs of the trip.**
>
> Evidence of your employment and/or your family ties may be sufficient to show the purpose of your trip and your intent to return to your home country. **If you cannot cover all the costs for your trip, you may show evidence that another person will cover some or all costs for your trip.**
>
> **Note:** Visa applicants must qualify on the basis of the applicant's residence and ties abroad, rather than assurances from U.S. family and friends. A letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support is not needed to apply for a visitor visa. **If you choose to bring a letter of invitation or Affidavit of Support to your interview, please remember it is not one of the factors used in determining whether to issue or deny the visa.**