# Does every tourist need a sponsor?

Tags: schengen

I looked up information on visiting Schengen countries and one of the requirements is having a sponsor. What if there is no sponsor but a person wants to travel the area for a few weeks for fun and entertainment? Is this not possible any more?

Comment: Not at all, where did you read this?

Comment: Citizenship...?

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Does that actually make a difference in this case? Can't people of any nationality get a Schengen visa to just be a tourist without needing to know an EU citizen?

Comment: @Guido your comment is valid as an answer!

Comment: There is no requirement for a sponsor, this only arises if the applicant isn’t covering the trip expenses personally. If the main purpose of travel is an invitation from friends/family to visit, the applicant is asked to provide their details, otherwise you state the accommodation details eg hotel name.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Visitors from a lot of countries don't even need visas, unless staying for >90 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sponsors are usually not required.

Tourists can visit the Schengen area without being sponsored. However, there are a few things which might have caused the misconception.

- A business traveler would have to explain where he or she is going. That's not the *sponsor*, it is the *destination* for the trip.
- A tourist who cannot afford the travel out of her or his own income needs to explain who pays and why. That's not the *sponsor*, it is the *source of money* for the trip. Often the person who pays is not in the Schengen area.
- In some cases, a sponsor can help to get a Schengen visa that would otherwise be refused. Such a sponsor would come from the Schengen state that is to be visited. This is **not necessary** if the traveler has stable economic circumstances and strong ties to the home country.

Comment: Correct, except that the bolded "No" at the front is a little unfortunate if taken as an answer to the question at the end of the question _body_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, better now?